# Array values returning undefined in console/Round array elements to integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I'm using the Highcharts JS charting library with the draggable points plugin for a project. I can set my array values up and have them generated fine. But when I try to change the Y value for any given array element by dragging the point up or down, the console returns the element as undefined. Any ideas why?

Code:

```
drag: function (e) {
    // Returning false stops the drag and drops. Example:
    $('#drag').html('Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.newY, 0) + '</b>');                   
},
drop: function () {
    $('#drop').html('In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + '</b>');
    console.log( array.map(function(c) { return c[1]; }) );
}
```

Another problem is that the Y values aren't integers so if anyone knows how to round array elements to integers that could work

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please? Thanks.

Comment: I'll try xD really new to js

Comment: @PawełFus http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/1568/

Comment: Ah, it's simple - after updating point, it's format was changed from `[x_value, y_value]` to: `{x: x_value, y: y_value}`. So instead of `c[1]`, use `c.y` for updated points.

Comment: @PawełFus thanks :) that half works. It changes the element that was undefined to its value, but changes the other values to undefined

Comment: Yes, because it is changing only points that were updated, not previous ones. So you need to check if it's using old format or new format (array vs object).

Comment: @PawełFus is there a way to do this without making any values undefined?

Comment: Just check if `c[1]` or `c.y` is undefined and then use other format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating point, format is changed from `[x_value, y_value]` to: `{x: x_value, y: y_value}`. So instead of `c[1]`, use `c.y` for updated points. Since both formats are used you need to check which one is use.